# VBA/Excel: Issue with refreshing .printarea

Tags: excel, vba

*UPDATE* This issue only occurs when I call it from my other macro.

```
Sub DAForm2062()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Clear
If DAFillFunc() Then
PDFGenerator
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This sub prints the amount of pages based on whether or not a certain amount of items were added to a list. The problem I'm experiencing is that the .printarea does not update every time I print something. It prints with the old .printarea and then if I print the form again it prints with the new .printarea and the correct amount of pages.

I've tried resetting the .printarea from where I call the PDFGenerator in another sub, I've tried forcing it to calculate, adding wait time, but none of that seemed to do the trick.

```
Sub PDFGenerator()
    Dim savePath As String
    Dim ws2062 As Worksheet
    Dim printArea As Range
    Dim currentPage As Long
    Dim totalPages As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    ' Set default page range as 10
    totalPages = 10
    ' Set the worksheet and print area range
    Set ws2062 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2062")
    Set printArea = ws2062.Range("A1:U248")

    ' Determine the actual number of pages based on data
    If ws2062.Range("E27").Value = "" Then
        Set printArea = ws2062.Range("A1:U23")
        totalPages = 1
    ElseIf ws2062.Range("E52").Value = "" Then
        Set printArea = ws2062.Range("A1:U48")
        totalPages = 2
    ElseIf ws2062.Range("E77").Value = "" Then
        Set printArea = ws2062.Range("A1:U73")
        totalPages = 3
    ElseIf ws2062.Range("E102").Value = "" Then
        Set printArea = ws2062.Range("A1:U98")
        totalPages = 4
    ElseIf ws2062.Range("E127").Value = "" Then
        Set printArea = ws2062.Range("A1:U123")
        totalPages = 5
    ElseIf ws2062.Range("E152").Value = "" Then
        Set printArea = ws2062.Range("A1:U148")
        totalPages = 6
    ElseIf ws2062.Range("E177").Value = "" Then
        Set printArea = ws2062.Range("A1:U173")
        totalPages = 7
    ElseIf ws2062.Range("E202").Value = "" Then
        Set printArea = ws2062.Range("A1:U198")
        totalPages = 8
    ElseIf ws2062.Range("E227").Value = "" Then
        Set printArea = ws2062.Range("A1:U223")
        totalPages = 9
    End If

    ' Update the page numbers
    For currentPage = 1 To totalPages
        ws2062.Range("R" & (currentPage * 25 - 2) & ":U" & (currentPage * 25 - 2)).Value = "Page " & currentPage & " of " & totalPages
    Next currentPage
    
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = False
        .printArea = printArea.Address
        .FitToPagesWide = False
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        .Zoom = 87
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.4)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)

    End With
    'ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks 'Used during creation to reset page breaks and layout of the pdf, activate then de-activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("2062")).Select
    
    'Location of the workbook and Updated 2062's folder. I place mine on the desktop.
    savePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Updated 2062's\"

    If Dir(savePath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir savePath
    End If
'Saves to savePath
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=savePath & "DA Form 2062 " & ActiveSheet.Shapes("To").TextFrame.Characters.text & Format(Date, " - yyyymmdd"), _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
        
ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Description Like "*Document not saved*" Then
        MsgBox "The PDF is already open. Close it and try again.", vbExclamation, "File Already Open"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? Side note 1: Why are you setting `printarea` to be a range when you could just use a string of the address since that is what you use in the end? Side note 2: I would use a different variable name as `printArea` is a property of `PageSetup`

Comment: Good call, thank you. I'm not very good at this yet I'm learning and researching as I go. That didn't fix the issue I'm experiencing though. The problem is stemming because I'm calling for the PDFGenerator in another macro, and that's why it's not updating. I'm just not sure how to make sure it updates?

Comment: This line: `ws2062 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2062")` -- you are aware that `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook with the macro. Maybe you need `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: It is the workbook with the macro, I figured it out using a Parameter and identifying the pArea from the other macro.

Answer (score 0):

Since I isolated the issue to it being run from another Sub in conjunction with other projects I added a parameter and set the pArea from my other macro.

```
    Sub DAForm2062()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws2062 As Worksheet
    Dim pArea As String
    Dim currentPage As Long
    Dim totalPages As Long
    
    ' Set default page range as 10
    totalPages = 10
    ' Set the worksheet and print area range
    Set ws2062 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2062")
    pArea = "A1:U248"
Clear
DAFillFunc
    If ws2062.Range("E27").Value = "" Then
        pArea = "A1:U23"
        totalPages = 1
    ElseIf ws2062.Range("E52").Value = "" Then
        pArea = "A1:U48"
        totalPages = 2
    ElseIf ws2062.Range("E77").Value = "" Then
        pArea = "A1:U73"
        totalPages = 3
    ElseIf ws2062.Range("E102").Value = "" Then
        pArea = "A1:U98"
        totalPages = 4
    ElseIf ws2062.Range("E127").Value = "" Then
        pArea = "A1:U123"
        totalPages = 5
    ElseIf ws2062.Range("E152").Value = "" Then
        pArea = "A1:U148"
        totalPages = 6
    ElseIf ws2062.Range("E177").Value = "" Then
        pArea = "A1:U173"
        totalPages = 7
    ElseIf ws2062.Range("E202").Value = "" Then
        pArea = "A1:U198"
        totalPages = 8
    ElseIf ws2062.Range("E227").Value = "" Then
        pArea = "A1:U223"
        totalPages = 9
    End If
        For currentPage = 1 To totalPages
        ws2062.Range("R" & (currentPage * 25 - 2) & ":U" & (currentPage * 25 - 2)).Value = "Page " & currentPage & " of " & totalPages
    Next currentPage
    ws2062.PageSetup.printArea = pArea
PDFGenerator pArea
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub



    Sub PDFGenerator(pArea As String)
    Dim savePath As String
    Dim ws2062 As Worksheet
    Dim currentPage As Long
    Dim totalPages As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = False
        .printArea = pArea
        .FitToPagesWide = False
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        .Zoom = 87
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.4)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    End With
    'ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks 'Used during creation to reset page breaks and layout of the pdf, activate then de-activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("2062")).Select
    
    'Location of the workbook and Updated 2062's folder. I place mine on the desktop.
    savePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Updated 2062's\"

    If Dir(savePath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir savePath
    End If
'Saves to savePath
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=savePath & "DA Form 2062 " & ActiveSheet.Shapes("To").TextFrame.Characters.text & Format(Date, " - yyyymmdd"), _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnoreprintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
        
ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Description Like "*Document not saved*" Then
        MsgBox "The PDF is already open. Close it and try again.", vbExclamation, "File Already Open"
    End If
End Sub
```